# Quartz.NET stops triggering after random durations

Tags: c#, cron, scheduler, quartz.net

I have Quartz.NET scheduler (inside a Windows service) running every 15 minute using a cron expression as `0 0/15 * * * ?`.

It runs well for a random amount of time, usually more than 2 days and not more than 5 days.

My log4net logger is configured to append a line every time the scheduler is triggered and that is how I will know it has stopped.

I have checked Windows event viewer for any unhandled exception and found nothing. Is there any way with Quartz.net to find out what's going wrong inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar scenario that runs without issues for months so I have no idea what goes wrong in your scenario. However, Quartz.NET uses Common Logging that I have configured in my application so I can give you my relevant configuration sections so you can configure logging for Quartz.NET.

First: the required config sections:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
  </sectionGroup>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  ...
</configSections>
```

Second: my Quartz.NET configuration. My job store is SQL Server.

```
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="3" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS" />
  <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Development;Integrated Security=True" />
  <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
</quartz>
```

And finally the logging configuration:

```
<common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
      <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging>
</common>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RootAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Log\Service.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=" dd-MM-yyyy" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="All" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %-5level %property{UsnSearchKey} (%logger) %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="RootAppender" />
  </root>
  <!-- Specify minimum logging level for Quartz logger. -->
  <logger name="Quartz">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

This configuration should create a `Service.log` file inside a `c:\Log` directory that has the debug log statements for Quartz.NET.

Comment: Your answer indeed helped me. However, in order to resolve the issue, I am trying out a different approach which I think should fix it. Earlier, I was instantiating different `Scheduler` objects for 3 different `Job`s I had, and the objects were scoped to a method. Now I have a single static `Scheduler` object through which I run all these 3 jobs. I think the GC was deallocating all `Scheduler` objects after some time. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Maybe possible but unlikely because of the timing. I would expect these schedulers to be garbage-collected much sooner than 2 to 5 days if this was indeed the problem. A static scheduler is tied to your AppDomain so it will not become eligible for garbage collection. I hope this solves your issue.